# How can i change my WordPress site mobile logo which is linked to another source?

Tags: headers, mobile, logo

Please have a look at this sites mobile header. I was trying to change logo but its not working and also tried to find out the source and change but it's source is another link and i don't know how to change the link. can anyone help please?

https://www.basicinteriorbd.com/
Thanks!

Comment: there's no code in your question, a quick look at the HTML/CSS heavily implies this theme was built using Elementor and that you should ask this in an Elementor community since questions about 3rd party themes/plugins/products are offtopic here. This is a stack for programmers so it's expected you'll be a programmer with code to share, please edit your question to include that and any other information you have